# Continuity problem $f(x,y)=\frac{\ln(1+x^3+y^3)}{|x|+|y|}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem is to check if function:

$f(x,y)=\frac{\ln(1+x^3+y^3)}{|x|+|y|}$, when $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$;

$f(x,y)=0$ when, $(x,y)= (0,0)$

is continuable or not continuable in point $(0,0)$.

I thought of using a squeeze theorem to check weather it's continuable or not, but I can't seem to solve it properly. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that $\ln(1+t) \to t$ as $t \to 0$. Because of this, $f(x,y)$ is asymptotically equivalent to the following function as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$:
$$g(x) = \frac{x^3 + y^3}{|x|+|y|},\ (x,y) \to (0,0)$$
It is easy to prove that $g(x)$ tends to $0$ as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$ along any path. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I just did, thank You!

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb I think that in this form the asnwer is not completely correct. Maybe we should say that $f(x,y)$ behaves as (i.e. asymptotically equivalent to) $$g(x,y)=\frac{x^3 + y^3}{|x|+|y|},\ (x,y) \to (0,0)$$ rather than we "can rewrite f(x,y) as...".

Comment: @user yep, thanks for pointing that out. Edited as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{\ln(1+x^3+y^3)}{|x|+|y|}=\frac{\ln(1+x^3+y^3)}{x^3+y^3}\frac{x^3+y^3}{|x|+|y|}$$

with

$$\frac{\ln(1+x^3+y^3)}{x^3+y^3}\to 1$$

by standard limits and by polar coordinates

$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{|x|+|y|} =r^2 \left(\frac{\cos^3\theta +\sin^3 \theta}{|\cos \theta|+|\sin \theta|}\right) \to 0$$